# HBase: MasterNotRunningException: the node /hbase is not in zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, cloudera

I'm building a pipeline with streamsets to read data from a kafka topic and write it to a HBase table. I am able to write it to an HDFS file, but when I try to use an HBase destination I get the following error:

[image: Streamsets error]

I'm using cloudera to manage the services, and I configured the following properties on the HBase destination:

```
Zookeeper quorum : (my zookeeeper server IP^)
Zookeeper client port: 2181
Zookeeper parent znode: /hbase
```

I've the following configuration on the HBase Cloudera service:

```
zookeeper.znode.parent: /hbase
```

so there isn't a mismatch between the indicated parameters.

What can be happening?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look over your Zookeeper server IP address. You should give the IP of the Zookeper that is in the **same cluster as HBase**. If you have multiple clusters managed by Cloudera Manager you may have multiple Zookeeper services in different clusters.

It is ok to use a Zookeper service for Kafka from one cluster and a different one from another cluster as long as StreamSets is configured accordingly.